# Remove app preview from iOS 7 multitasking

Tags: ios, application-switcher

Using an iPad Mini, I preferred the paged, compact style of the app
switcher in iOS 6. In iOS 7 it is replaced by a scrolling interface
where I see 4 app-icons at a time at best and have the huge preview
cards quickly swishing through the screen.

While I can imagine the preview to become useful when e.g. writing in
one app and occasionally needing to steal a glance at another app
without actually switching apps, most of the time I find them merely
distracting; Especially the largely different movement speed of the
preview cards and the app icons.

Are there any possibilities to configure the behaviour/design of this
interface short of a jailbreak?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't configurable on iOS 7.

We'll have to see what the jailbreak community comes up with for people wanting an alternate idiom or design for fast switching of apps.

As a sidenote, you can still use four finger swipe gestures to switch apps.

Comment: I know about the swipe gestures. On iOS 6 however I was often switching 20 apps back in time rather than going to the homescreen; With iOS 7 going to the homescreen suddenly is the most efficient solution, even though the new animations make switching to the homescreen slightly annoying.

Comment: @kdb - I still am not fast enough with spotlight (and siri can open apps, but not as fast as I'd like) to get to that app I want. I too missed the old tray with the apps that was quick to swipe, swipe, swipe to get to a distinctive icon.